# Testing pH levels through urine or saliva

Tags: urine, saliva, ph-levels, sibo, prostatitis

I am attempting to discover the role of pH in contributing to my mysteriously fluctuating chronic symptoms, including small and large intestine problems (apparent Candida, SIBO, etc.), male reproductive system issues (prostatitis, low quality orgasm, low libido, etc.), every flavor of fatigue, rectal itch, and leg cramps (leg cramps could possibly be correlated with probiotic use:  http://en.allexperts.com/q/Naturopathy-3401/2009/5/f/probiotics-cause-joint-pain.htm [unfortunately, I have to remain on probiotics to keep prostate pain at bay]).

I have read that urine and saliva pH are not good indicators of blood pH.  My question is whether or not urine and/or saliva pH could be a good indicator of pH in the small or large intestines, in the reproductive system, or in any other particular part of the body.  What relevant information can these tests really show?